# IIS error 404 even file existsn, aspx opens normally

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I am not being able to access the html pages or any image files , only I am able to access successful .apsx  asmx and ashx files. I am getting **404 - File or directory not found**

For example :

```
mysite.com/index.html  ( getting 404 error)
mysite.com/image.jpg( getting 404 error)

mysite.com/page.aspx (working fine)
mysite.com/service.asmx/method  ( working fine)
```

Things I have tried to do :

1. Checking the folder permissions for IUSR and IIS_IUSRS are there.
2. MIME TYPES
3. Mapping Handlers

and I will post my web.config settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="PHP5" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\******\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
      <add name="uploadfile" path="uploadfile.ashx" verb="*" type="Namespace.uploadfile" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SalikConnection" connectionString="Data Source=**************;Initial Catalog=*****;uid=*****;password=****************;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

any suggestions ?

**EDITED & SOLVED**

Adding Static Contents to the web.config

```
 <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
           <clear />
            <add 
                name="StaticFile" 
                path="*" verb="*" 
                modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" 
                resourceType="Either" 
                requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that you have Static Content checkbox selected under IIS in Windows features dialog. Check the screenshot

[Static Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUQpp.png)

Comment: It is checked , on the same server other sites are working well

Comment: For the website, go to IIS manager and then check the handler mappings. Ensure StaticFile handler is listed

Comment: Done , thank you I will edit my post for future reference.

Comment: When the Static files , now aspx page is downloading instead of opening. so how to fix it ?

Comment: Check do you have aspx handler in the handlers mappings.

Comment: Check do you have aspx handler in the handlers mappings. I noticed that you added clear before adding static file handler which will clear all previous handlers
 <handlers>
           <clear />
            <add 
                name="StaticFile" 
                path="*" verb="*" 
                modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" 
                resourceType="Either" 
                requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>

Just add static file handler in addition to previous handlers

Comment: Yes clear is not there in my real code , and once i remove the static handler aspx are working , means aspx handlers are there also , only once I add static handler aspx not working.

Comment: Check the order of handlers. Static file handler should be the last in the handlers list. Compare the order with working website

Comment: I just clicked revert to parent ,and added the php handler because I need it and all are working fine now , thanks